# Django tag cloud plugin

Tags: django, tag-cloud

Is there a good Django app out there that can take a list of tags and their frequencies of occurrence and render a tag cloud for them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) has helpers for generating tag clouds.

Comment: Seems the django-tagging project is dead or dying, with lots of showstopper bugs in the issue tracker with no movement for many months...

Comment: @Epcylon a 1.0 compatibility update was JUST released (0.3)

Answer (score 4):

A little self-promotion never hurt anybody, right?  http://dburke.info/blog/logarithmic-tag-clouds

Comment: Gives "Internal Server Error" as of 2012-07-21. Please flag for deletion if this is still true in a few weeks.

Comment: 200 as of 9 August 2012.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this template tag:
http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/140/

It works with the django-tagging app
http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/

Answer (score 1):

Grab the trunk and it will work for 1.0

Answer (score 0):

currently facing the same issue, i found that these links are useful for the tagging template -- so you wouldn't have to type all the template for tagging from scratch:

- http://www.napes.co.uk/blog/django-tagging/
- http://tylerlesmann.com/2009/mar/09/adding-tagging-django-10-views-and-templates/

hopefully those can help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is shameless self promotion, but I just released a very simple template tag helper to do this as I had the same need and didn't wanted to use something heavier such as Django-tagging.

It doesn't render the tag cloud tough, but it makes the necessary calculations and store the result in an attribute that can be easily referenced in HTML/CSS.

https://github.com/niconoe/django-nuages-tag